# I'm having trouble fixing chechboxlisttile in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, checkbox, dart-null-safety

I can't seem to find a suitable solution fixing checkboxlisttile in a flutter, I'm a complete beginner working with flutter I went through the flutter docs [CheckboxListTile class](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwjWgquh59P5AhXsxgIHHYleAyAQFnoECAMQAQ&url=https%3A%2F%2Fapi.flutter.dev%2Fflutter%2Fmaterial%2FCheckboxListTile-class.html&usg=AOvVaw3R8ZWag8JXjYf0h2MNGf-0) and it's not working for me.

Please I needed help in understanding this checkboxlisttile thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to toggle between true and false upon clicking the `CheckBoxListTile`.

Edit the following code inside your onChanged:

```
onChanged: (bool? value){
 isChecked = !isChecked;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onChanged` provides nullable bool

> final ValueChanged<bool?>? onChanged;

```dart
onChanged: (bool? value){
 isChecked = value ?? false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped my code in a StatelessWidget instead of StatefulWidget, by doing so, i now fixed the problem. CheckboxListTile is now working thank you all for helping.
This is the screenshot of my code sample before and after.
[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I also rename my class name to MySales

Comment: Avoid posting code-image , find more about [Why should I not upload images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/10157127)

Comment: Oh! thank you i did't know that.

Comment: Glad to help, you can find more [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)